# psiturk -- how can I verify that a live HIT is actually valid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I created a live HIT on Wednesday with a duration of 2 hours. Part way through the HIT, I tried to open it on the same computer that I created it on and got an error (#1018 I believe). This had me thinking that the HIT wasn't working.

I also searched through the mTurk site for the experiment and couldn't find it there, further confirming to me that the HIT wasn't working.

Here's the [server.log](https://paste.ee/p/gmbM3) from this HIT, in case it's somehow useful -- all the errors that it's riddled with furthered my belief that the HIT wasn't working.

The next day, the researcher I'm an assistant to forwarded me an email from an angry worker saying she completed the whole thing, but couldn't hit the final "continue" button to submit her work and get paid. So the HIT *had* been working the whole time, but was completely unapparent to myself and the researcher I work for.

There must be a more stable way to tell if the experiment is working...I can't just spend large chunks of my day waiting around without actually knowing if the HIT is working, since so often it doesn't. The assistant before me said he would stop/start the server multiple times, waiting 3-5 minutes in between, until the HIT showed up on the mTurk site. Is this really the best method out there?

**I have multiple questions about this same experience, but SO policy is one question per post...so please look for my other questions**

Answer (score 1):

If you type "hit list" in psiturk you should get something like this:

```
Perception Experiment 
Status: Assignable 
HITid: 3IKMEYR0LWDA7K7OS5D2SUOVHWD2KK             
max:15/pending:0/complete:0/remain:14 
Created:2015-08-24T19:21:51Z             
Expires:2015-08-24T21:21:51Z
```

Then you can check what a worker would see (note the HITid is copied from above):

https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=3IKMEYR0LWDA7K7OS5D2SUOVHWD2KK

In addition, if you login to your requester account on requestersandbox.mturk.com, go to Manage, then "Manage Hits Individually", you should see the same output that typing "hit list" in psiturk returns.

In general though, it sounds like your workflow isn't quite ready for using MTurk in production mode. I would recommend the following:

- Run your HIT first in sandbox mode, do it yourself as a test requester and have at least one other person do it.
- If all goes well and you can download_datafiles AND run your analysis (i.e. you aren't forgetting any crucial variables...), then run it for 3-5 MTurkers live.
- If all goes well, run your full experiment.